# switch to different mode of network in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am making an app where the user taps on a button , then if he is already in the cellular network , then switches to "wifi" network .

If the user is in the "wi-fi" network , then switches to "cellular" network. 
But how to detect the type of network ?
and how to detect different **kinds** of networks available ?

Comment: So you are making and app that switches from wifi to cellular and back? I'm assuming you are jailbreaking the device. Otherwise that kind of stuff is for the OS to handle and there is already a UI for it in the settings app.

Comment: Basically you can ask this from user at your app launch- use wifi? or use cellular? or use wifi/cellular?
Based upon the choice, you can work upon detecting networks- see more in http://iostipsntricks.wordpress.com/tag/detect-network-connection-in-ios/

Comment: No priya , the application is basically using wifi , but incase the user wants to use internet through cellular network , then it would have to do the thing which i have asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting networks, you can refer this post

http://iostipsntricks.wordpress.com/tag/detect-network-connection-in-ios/

Answer (score 1):

[Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/) can help to detect type of network, but it seems no public API for switching the network in Apple's Documents.